# Updating tooltip in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

I have a graph which has multiple series in highcharts. I am giving the data to these graphs via handlebars. Now i am updating them dynamically using the data from AJAX call. I am able to update the data to the graphs. But i am not able to figure out how to update the tooltip of the series. Here is the code i am using for the tooltip.

```
series: [
    {{#each histData as |index|}}
    {
        name: '{{@key}}',
        id: '{{@key}}',
        type: 'spline',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        {{#each index as |status|}}
        {{#if_eq @key "histSuccess"}}
        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function(){
            var toolTip = [{{this}}];
              return "Index: {{@../key}}" + "<br />" + "Failure: " + this.y + "%" + "<br />" + "Success: " + toolTip[this.series.data.indexOf( this )] + "%" + "<br />";
            }
        },
        {{/if_eq}}
        {{#if_eq @key "histFailure"}} 
        data: [{{this}}],
        {{/if_eq}}
        {{/each}}
    },
    {{/each}}
    ]
```

EDIT:

This is how i am updating the data in the graph.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    headers: { 'x-cyclops-ajax': 'yes' },
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var keys = Object.keys(data["histData"]);
        for( var i=0; i< keys.length; i++) {
            chart.series[i].setData(data["histData"][keys[i]]["histFailure"], true);
        }
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(data["histKeys"]);
        console.log("Data:");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Did not hit the AJAX call");
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update the tooltip"? The tooltip should show whatever is in the data. What is it doing that is problematic?

Comment: @jlbriggsI have updated the code in the edit. I am updating the data in the charts series. I have a customized tooltip. So i want new data to be shown in the tooltip. That's what i am not able to figure out.

Comment: I'm still not clear. Do you mean that you need to update the `formatter` to grab different elements of the data once it's updated? That's going to be some what more complicated. If you have a known number of set ups that you need, you can do some `if` or `case` statements in the formatter function - check which data you're looking at, and return the appropriate information. If it's truly dynamic, it will be more difficult.

Comment: With updating data as in your code, you don't need to update the tooltip manually. So if you have a problem with displaying updated data, it might be because some magic behind your template made by handlebars. It would be helpful if you create a live example of the issue (jsfiddle/codepen/etc.). Also, try to not use handlebars inside a tooltip formatter, use pure js.